# Wildflt 13 WELD-001304: More than one context active for scope type javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped

Tags: jsf, cdi, weld, deltaspike

A JEE application I am looking at sometimes - no idea why it happens -  goes into this wel exception.

```
 WELD-001304: More than one context active for scope type javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.internalGetContext(BeanManagerImpl.java:678)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getContext(BeanManagerImpl.java:645)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$DefaultContextualInstanceStrategy.getIfExists(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:89)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$CachingContextualInstanceStrategy.getIfExists(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:164)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstance.getIfExists(ContextualInstance.java:63)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ContextBeanInstance.getInstance(ContextBeanInstance.java:87)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.getInstance(ProxyMethodHandler.java:131)
    at org.apache.deltaspike.core.impl.scope.window.WindowBeanHolder$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.getContextualStorage(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.deltaspike.core.impl.scope.window.WindowContextImpl.getContextualStorage(WindowContextImpl.java:119)
    at org.apache.deltaspike.core.util.context.AbstractContext.get(AbstractContext.java:78)
    at org.jboss.weld.contexts.PassivatingContextWrapper$AbstractPassivatingContextWrapper.get(PassivatingContextWrapper.java:70)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$DefaultContextualInstanceStrategy.getIfExists(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:89)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstance.getIfExists(ContextualInstance.java:63)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ContextBeanInstance.getInstance(ContextBeanInstance.java:87)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.getInstance(ProxyMethodHandler.java:131)
    at org.apache.deltaspike.core.impl.scope.viewaccess.ViewAccessViewHistory$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.getLastView(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.deltaspike.core.impl.scope.viewaccess.ViewAccessContext.close(ViewAccessContext.java:131)
    at org.apache.deltaspike.core.impl.scope.viewaccess.ViewAccessContext.onProcessingViewFinished(ViewAccessContext.java:119)
    at org.apache.deltaspike.jsf.impl.listener.request.DeltaSpikeLifecycleWrapper.render(DeltaSpikeLifecycleWrapper.java:118)
    at javax.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleWrapper.render(LifecycleWrapper.java:92)
    at org.apache.deltaspike.jsf.impl.listener.request.JsfClientWindowAwareLifecycleWrapper.render(JsfClientWindowAwareLifecycleWrapper.java:160)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:659)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
```

It is not clear why this is happening.
And the side effects are not always the same.
Some times when this situation happens, you really need to restart the server, eve if you try to loging in incognito mode with a different browser.
It is as if the BeanManager from WELD has become completely toasted.

This error is coming most often when you sleep your computer and the next day you start interacting with the application.
But interesting enough, this is also happening quite often if I start triggering selinum tests.
Have no idea why the selenium testing would exacerbate the exception.

What I have seen now by putting a break point, is that we have WELD trying to resolve some injection point annotations.
At some point, one of the injeaction points it wants to resolve is a:

```
at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ContextBeanInstance.getInstance(ContextBeanInstance.java:87)

    It is doing a 
          T existingInstance = ContextualInstance.getIfExists(bean, manager);
          Where the Managed Bean 
            parameter bean = [class org.apache.deltaspike.core.impl.scope.window.WindowBeanHolder] with qualifiers [@Any @Default]
          It is tring to resolve the bean injext:
            [[BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private org.apache.deltaspike.core.impl.scope.window.WindowBeanHolder.windowContextQuotaHandler]
          Into the bean:
                Managed Bean [class org.apache.deltaspike.jsf.impl.scope.window.JsfWindowContextQuotaHandler] with qualifiers [@Any @Default]
```

This window bean holder (could be any other bean I believe, it is irrelevant) is annotated with the session scoped annotation:

```
@SessionScoped
public class WindowBeanHolder extends AbstractBeanHolder<String>
{
```

And the system then breaks because the wildfly beanmanager impl, when it enter the logic of returning the SessionScoped context at line 678:

```
 private Context internalGetContext(Class<? extends Annotation> scopeType) {
        Context activeContext = null;
        final List<Context> ctx = contexts.get(scopeType);
        if (ctx == null) {
            return null;
        }
        for (Context context : ctx) {
            if (context.isActive()) {
                if (activeContext == null) {
                    activeContext = context;
                } else {
                    throw BeanManagerLogger.LOG.duplicateActiveContexts(scopeType.getName());
                }
            }
        }
        return activeContext;
    }
```

This BeanManagerImpl code will not be happy with the fact that apparently a two SessionScopedContexts are at the same active.

In this code fragment what I see with the debugger is that the contexts variable is holding the following 3 session scoped contexts:
    [
        org.jboss.weld.contexts.bound.BoundSessionContextImpl@136b5782, 
        org.jboss.weld.module.web.context.http.HttpSessionContextImpl@6ef334ee,
        org.jboss.weld.module.web.context.http.HttpSessionDestructionContext@37a5a86e
    ]

```
The first ACTIVE CONTEXT found was:
    oactiveContext = rg.jboss.weld.module.web.context.http.HttpSessionContextImpl@6ef334ee
The second CONTEXT we have is:
    context = org.jboss.weld.module.web.context.http.HttpSessionDestructionContext@37a5a86e
```

That means for whatever reason, in my seystem both the HttpSessionContextImpl and the HttpSessionDestructionContext.

I am clueless is a to how these contexts are being toggled between ACTIVE/INACTIVE, if this is supposed to be "ThreadContext" specific flag that for a given thread the session scoped is corrupted but other threads with differ JESSESIONID cookie would start in an appropriate virgin state. where only one session context is active.

Any ideas of what could be causing this?

Note, widlfly 13.0.Final uses:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId>
    <artifactId>weld-core-impl</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.4.Final</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Many thanks

Comment: _oactiveContext = rg.jboss.weld.module.web.context.http.HttpSessionContextImpl@6ef334ee_ copy paste error I assume, the 'o' fell of 'org.jboss'. And can you make a [mcve] and try without DeltaSpike? You can btw set a breakpoint and see when the contexts are created to see the origin.

Comment: HI. The problem is I do not know how to reproduce the issue. It happens - but I do not know how to make it happen. The interesting thing as well, is that if I set a break point on the thread that is about to blow UP at line 678. I am then ablw to work normally. I can see during the JSF restore view that that HTTP session is the same between a thread working normally and a thread dying on this exception.  Both threads with JSESSIONID aakFE4yk8L_O6VxRankZYnrBCNuNQfDuQFXW_pvE . But on one of the requests only one of the session contexts was active. On the other both were.

Comment: Thread 64 going to blow up has session contexts:
[org.jboss.weld.contexts.bound.BoundSessionContextImpl@136b5782, 
org.jboss.weld.module.web.context.http.HttpSessionContextImpl@6ef334ee, 
org.jboss.weld.module.web.context.http.HttpSessionDestructionContext@37a5a86e]

Thread 70 that is functionaling normally has contexts:
[org.jboss.weld.contexts.bound.BoundSessionContextImpl@136b5782
, 
org.jboss.weld.module.web.context.http.HttpSessionContextImpl@6ef334ee
, org.jboss.weld.module.web.context.http.HttpSessionDestructionContext@37a5a86e]

For thread 64 both contexts were activated.

Comment: Did you read the api docs of HttpSessionDestructionContext https://github.com/doctau/weld-core/blob/master/impl/src/main/java/org/jboss/weld/context/http/HttpSessionDestructionContext.java? That might give you a lead maybe...

Comment: Thanks I will have a read.
I believe I need to get the source code for the following class.
And try to find out when it becomes ACTIVE .
jar:file:/C:/dev/appserver/wildfly/wildfly-13.0.0.Final/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/weld/core/main/weld-web-3.0.4.Final.jar!/org/jboss/weld/module/web/context/http/HttpSessionDestructionContext.class

Comment: Yes... And sorry I can't give you a direct answser. Did not encounter this myself and are just 'suggesting' things. Hoping it helps.

Comment: From reading the javadoc in the HttpSessionDestructionContext.java that yout pointed me to, I almost get the feeling that there the container problem is not ensuring in all situations that only one context is activated. It probably activates the context HttpSessionDestructionContext.java with good intentions, but forgets to deactivate the usual HTTP Session context. It looks to me as well that the HttpSessionDestructionContext.java should probabl be overring the isActive() method to always return FALSE when the request is being hanled in an HTTP request context (if that could be found out).

Comment: In the end the javadoc is saying. Because there might be session listeners that will get called when an HTTP request is not running, we have this additional context here that can work without an HTTP request coming in. But if that is the case - the HTTP SessioncontextImpl and the HttpSessionDestructionContext.java should be mutually exclusive. The Last one should only return that it is active if an HTTP request is not being processed. I feel tempted to just hack and patch this class.

Comment: Many thanks for your help. Right now I am going to interrupt for a bit the investigation on this issue. But as said above, i feel highly tempted to hack the the HttpSesionDescrutionContext and ensure that the is ACTIVE is only going to be returning true if the request is not part of an HTTP request call stack.  It would be preferable to get the root cause of the problem of course, but we shall see...

Comment: Yes, I've been looking in to classes using this too but do not seem to be able to find a big difference between this weld version and older ones. At least not ones that explain this. Maybe you could try running your application on wildfly 17 and see if it makes a difference... Or an older version

Comment: I have tried activating a breakpoint on:
org.jboss.weld.contexts.AbstractManagedContext
  protected void setActive(boolean active)

With break point conditional property:
 this.getClass().getName().contains("HttpSessionDestructionContext")

I am not sure if this lower the level of concurrency by slowing down my eclipse.
But right now I am not being able to reproduce the issue.
While the breakpoint on:
this.getClass().getName().contains("HttpSessionContextImpl")

Would be hit.
The one on DescrutionContext is not being hit at all...
Would like to get a breakpoint of when its active

Comment: OK. I believe I know what the issue is. I will post an answer soon... If I am correct, wildfly is very vulnerable in terms of how it handles the Session Timeouts...   I provide further details on an answer once I confir my theory.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is now understood.

This duplicate active session scoped context is caused by two factors.
First an application specific problem that only occurs in widlfy and not in weblogic.

Second a wildfly problem (this one is debatable it is a matter of opinion, but I believe wildfly should be more robust here).

The first problem.
Whenever an HTTP session becomes expired in wildfly / undertow, a session reaper process will kick in to terminate the session. Every application server has its own process of doing this.
The following stack trace snippet depicts what is going on when a session is being destoryed in wildfly.

```
####2019-11-19 16:40:49,522 ThreadId:441 ERROR org.jboss.threads.errors - Thread Thread[default task-4,5,main] threw an uncaught exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.jboss.weld.contexts.ContextNotActiveException: WELD-001303: No active contexts for scope type javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.SessionListenerBridge.sessionDestroyed(SessionListenerBridge.java:75)
    at io.undertow.server.session.SessionListeners.sessionDestroyed(SessionListeners.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.session.InMemorySessionManager$SessionImpl.invalidate(InMemorySessionManager.java:586)
    at io.undertow.server.session.InMemorySessionManager$SessionImpl$2$1.run(InMemorySessionManager.java:393)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1378)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.contexts.ContextNotActiveException: WELD-001303: No active contexts for scope type javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getContext(BeanManagerImpl.java:647)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$DefaultContextualInstanceStrategy.getIfExists(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:89)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$CachingContextualInstanceStrategy.getIfExists(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:164)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstance.getIfExists(ContextualInstance.java:63)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ContextBeanInstance.getInstance(ContextBeanInstance.java:87)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.getInstance(ProxyMethodHandler.java:131)
    at org.apache.deltaspike.core.impl.scope.window.WindowIdHolder$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.getWindowId(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.deltaspike.core.impl.scope.window.WindowContextImpl.getCurrentWindowId(WindowContextImpl.java:85)
    at org.apache.deltaspike.core.impl.scope.window.InjectableWindowContext.getCurrentWindowId(InjectableWindowContext.java:54)
    at com.XXXXX.YYYYY.framework.web.util.JsfUtilBean.getWindowId(JsfUtilBean.java:230)
    at com.XXXXX.YYYYY.framework.web.util.JsfUtilBean$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.getWindowId(Unknown Source)
    at com.XXXXX.YYYYY.framework.web.enterprisetouch.boxframework.push.SomeIrrlevantAppSpecificClass.logout(SomeIrrlevantAppSpecificClass.java:105)
    at com.XXXXX.YYYYY.framework.web.enterprisetouch.boxframework.push.SomeIrrlevantAppSpecificClass$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.logout(Unknown Source)
    at com.XXXXX.YYYYY.framework.web.client.YYYYYSessionController.sessionDestroyed(YYYYYSessionController.java:245)
    at com.XXXXX.YYYYY.framework.web.client.YYYYYSessionController$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.sessionDestroyed(Unknown Source)
    at com.XXXXX.YYYYY.framework.web.security.YYYYYSessionListener.sessionDestroyed(YYYYYSessionListener.java:80)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.sessionDestroyed(ApplicationListeners.java:315)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.SessionListenerBridge.doDestroy(SessionListenerBridge.java:98)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.SessionListenerBridge.access$000(SessionListenerBridge.java:41)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.SessionListenerBridge$1.call(SessionListenerBridge.java:54)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.SessionListenerBridge$1.call(SessionListenerBridge.java:51)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1514)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1514)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1514)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1514)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1514)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.SessionListenerBridge.sessionDestroyed(SessionListenerBridge.java:73)
    ... 8 more
```

The above stack trace is important for two reasons.
One it gives you an idea of how underdow decides to initiate killing of sessions that have timed out.
Second it is showing you a very real possibility on any application - it can break when handling a session destruction event.
The code that is blowing up the stack trace above works perfectly fine in weblogic, because we have a RequestScope active.
The code in wildfly is breaking because there is no request scope active.
So I have not fixed the code blowing up in the stack trace above yet because I wanted to find a hack to get myself out of the problem that was reported here - since this could happen agian in the future very easily.
So for me the request scope exception is irrelevant, what is relevat are the side effects that come after.

It is also very important to understand that before the code that is blowing up above was called something very important took place.
Namely the activation of what will be in the future the SECOND / DUPLICATION session scope context.
Please look at the stack trace that I will put bellow.
This stack trace takes place whenever UNDERTOW decides to initiate killing of sessions.
When this happens wildfly comes int and decides to activate the very special session scope context implementation that is used outside of HTTP requests.

```
-------------------
-- HTTP SESSION - DEACTIVATION:
---------------------
Thread [default task-102] (Suspended (breakpoint at line 41 in org.jboss.weld.contexts.AbstractManagedContext)) 
    org.jboss.weld.module.web.context.http.HttpSessionDestructionContext(org.jboss.weld.contexts.AbstractManagedContext).setActive(boolean) line: 41    
    org.jboss.weld.module.web.context.http.HttpSessionDestructionContext(org.jboss.weld.contexts.AbstractManagedContext).activate() line: 49    
    org.jboss.weld.module.web.context.http.HttpSessionDestructionContext(org.jboss.weld.contexts.AbstractBoundContext<S>).activate() line: 66   
    org.jboss.weld.module.web.servlet.WeldTerminalListener.sessionDestroyed(javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionEvent) line: 95   
    io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.sessionDestroyed(javax.servlet.http.HttpSession) line: 315    
    io.undertow.servlet.core.SessionListenerBridge.doDestroy(io.undertow.server.session.Session) line: 98   
    io.undertow.servlet.core.SessionListenerBridge.access$000(io.undertow.servlet.core.SessionListenerBridge, io.undertow.server.session.Session) line: 41  
    io.undertow.servlet.core.SessionListenerBridge$1.call(io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange, io.undertow.server.session.Session) line: 54   
    io.undertow.servlet.core.SessionListenerBridge$1.call(io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange, java.lang.Object) line: 51 
    io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange, C) line: 42   
    io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange, C) line: 43    
    org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(io.undertow.servlet.api.ThreadSetupHandler$Action, io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange, java.lang.Object) line: 105  
    org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction$$Lambda$764.660751084.call(io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange, java.lang.Object) line: not available    
    org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(io.undertow.servlet.api.ThreadSetupHandler$Action, io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange, java.lang.Object) line: 1514    
    org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction$$Lambda$765.1975131456.call(io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange, java.lang.Object) line: not available  
    org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(io.undertow.servlet.api.ThreadSetupHandler$Action, io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange, java.lang.Object) line: 1514    
    org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction$$Lambda$765.1975131456.call(io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange, java.lang.Object) line: not available  
    org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(io.undertow.servlet.api.ThreadSetupHandler$Action, io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange, java.lang.Object) line: 1514    
    org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction$$Lambda$765.1975131456.call(io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange, java.lang.Object) line: not available  
    org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(io.undertow.servlet.api.ThreadSetupHandler$Action, io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange, java.lang.Object) line: 1514    
    org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction$$Lambda$765.1975131456.call(io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange, java.lang.Object) line: not available  
    org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(io.undertow.servlet.api.ThreadSetupHandler$Action, io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange, java.lang.Object) line: 1514    
    org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction$$Lambda$765.1975131456.call(io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange, java.lang.Object) line: not available  
    io.undertow.servlet.core.SessionListenerBridge.sessionDestroyed(io.undertow.server.session.Session, io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange, io.undertow.server.session.SessionListener$SessionDestroyedReason) line: 73  
    io.undertow.server.session.SessionListeners.sessionDestroyed(io.undertow.server.session.Session, io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange, io.undertow.server.session.SessionListener$SessionDestroyedReason) line: 61 
    io.undertow.server.session.InMemorySessionManager$SessionImpl.invalidate(io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange, io.undertow.server.session.SessionListener$SessionDestroyedReason) line: 586    
    io.undertow.server.session.InMemorySessionManager$SessionImpl$2$1.run() line: 393   
    org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run() line: 35   
    org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(java.lang.Runnable) line: 1985  
    org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(java.lang.Runnable) line: 1487 
    org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run() line: 1378 
    java.lang.Thread.run() line: 748
```

This stack trace here is critical to understand.
So normally, on what we can call an happy HTTP request, widlfly will activate the following session scope context class.

```
org.jboss.weld.module.web.context.http.HttpSessionContextImpl(org.jboss.weld.contexts.AbstractManagedContext).setActive(boolean) line: 41
```

But as shown above, when it is time to kill of an http session, then instead it activates that other implementation class of a session scope the. The

```
org.jboss.weld.module.web.context.http.HttpSessionDestructionContext(org.jboss.weld.contexts.AbstractManagedContext).setActive(boolean) line: 41
```

So until here is the story clear?
Let us summarize until here.

(a) We have our application running happy
(b) We close our browser window and we let the http session timeout
(c) When undertow kills of the http session wildfly will acttivate the context HttpSessionDestructionContext
(d) Our application speific session listener that is curious about ending sessions will blow up because the request scope context is not active

(e) ... I suppose the story finishes up very badly, because wildfly would most likely have some nice class or logic to in the end of proper session termination to deactivate the HttpSessionDestructionContext but whatever this logic is and whatever makes it gets triggered, for this application it will NEVER get triggered.

So what are we left with at this point?
With a very subtle bug.
We finally have a very corrupted thread.
Whatever thread undertow used to kill of the session is now forever doomed to not support any more the session scoped context.
Why?
Because when you look at the implementation of these session contexts, you will see their state of being ative or not active is a THREAD LOCAL variable.
What this means is for as long as this thread lives, the state it had fro the previous run will remain.

And here is where Wildfly is having a problem, in my opinion.

Widlfly could either have a "pre-emptive" cleanup logic that tries to make sure that before a thread is used to handover a request the thread local variables are cleaned up to avoid going on ahead with a dirty thread.

Or  it would need to have some sort of resilience mechanism to make sure that when it activates a scope in the context of a running thread, before the thread finishes well or bad, that the scope is ultimately deactivated.

Ok.

To finalize.
So now we have an application that blew up and as reward this applicaton now has one thread that is toasted.
This issue is normally very difficult to reproduce because you normally do not have a very low timeout.
So you have the feeling that this issue comes when you leave your applicaton server running for extended period time. Like you go home, put your computer to sleep and the next morning everything is blowing up (because all of your http sesisons have timed out since then).
The best way to make this issue reproducible, is to go t your standalone.xml and set it up like this:

```
 <servlet-container name="default" default-session-timeout="1">
        <jsp-config/>
        <websockets/>
    </servlet-container>
```

You set the timeout of a session to run every minute.
Then with chrome you just open an icognito window loging to your application to get the JESSIONID created and close the window.
Open a different iconito window login again and close again.
Repeat this for many sessions.

Then in parallel, what you can do as well, is make sure that you set a DEBUG BREAKPOINT on the

```
org.jboss.weld.contexts.AbstractManagedContext
```

Put the break point on the method:

```
protected void setActive(boolean active) {
    getManagedState().setActive(active);
}
```

Put in there the following breakpoint condition:

```
this.getClass().getName().contains("HttpSessionDestructionContext")
```

What this break point will allow you to do is to make sure that when UNDERTOW starts killing of your sessions, you block the thread and that forces the killing process of the sessions to go over multiple different threds.
The larger the number of different threads that have been used to terminate sessions, the more threads you have corrupted, the more likely you are to re-use the thread in the future in a normal http request that will blow up with this error.
Essentially, you are just simulating what in a normal production server might take hours to happen.
In a productive server a session can be active for many hours if a user is active, unitl he goes home or whatever.
And the next day is when you start having threads in your thread pool that are unsuable.

Ok to finalize.
Soon I will be fixing that code that wsa breaking due to the lack request scope context.
But before that, I want to make sure i am somehow able to heal my widlfly threads in case in the future this situation happes again.

To do this I am using a servlet listener as shown bellow.
(the usage of listener and helper as separate classes has to do with now having the WAR file blow up when you try to deploy on weblogic and weblogic might complain it has no idea of what this org.jboss.weld.module.web.context.http.HttpSessionDestructionContext is about).

```
package wahteverpackage;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequestEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequestListener;

import LALALLA.commons.util.constants.CommonsConstants;
import LALALLA.commons.util.util.BasicApplicationServerIdentificationUtil;


@ApplicationScoped
public class LALALLAWildflyWELD001304ServletRequestListener implements ServletRequestListener {

    /**
     * The issue takes place after an http session is timed out and a subsequent http request is handled by the thread
     * that managed the timeout that thread is corrupted. So we want to fix the corrupted thread that is handling na
     * http request.
     */
    private static final List<String> RELEVANT_SERVLET_REQUEST_PROTOCOLS = Arrays.asList("http", "https");

    @Inject
    BeanManager beanManager;

    final String appServerName;
    final Boolean isWildfly;

    /**
     * Create a new LALALLAWildflyWELD001304ServletRequestListener.
     *
     */
    public LALALLAWildflyWELD001304ServletRequestListener() {
        super();
        appServerName = BasicApplicationServerIdentificationUtil.getApplicationServerName();
        isWildfly = CommonsConstants.WILDFLY.equals(appServerName);
    }

    @Override
    public void requestDestroyed(ServletRequestEvent sre) {
        // on request destroyed we do not care to do no anything
    }

    @Override
    public void requestInitialized(ServletRequestEvent sre) {
        // (a) We only want this code to have any effect if it is running in wildfly
        if (!isWildfly) {
            return;
        }
        // (a) Make sure we are dealing with an http servlet request

        if (!isHttpServletRequest(sre)) {
            return;
        }

        // (b) We only want to intervene in the request if the current thread
        // be broken by the multiple contexts active exception
        LALALLAWildflyWELD001304ServletRequestListenerHelper helper = new LALALLAWildflyWELD001304ServletRequestListenerHelper();
        if (!helper.isCurrentThreadCorruptedWithWELD001304Exception(beanManager)) {
            return;
        }

        helper.tryToRepairCorruptedThread(beanManager);

    }

    /**
     * Check if we are dealing with an http servlet request.
     *
     * @param sre
     *            the servlet request
     * @return TRUE if we are dealing with an http servlet request
     */
    protected boolean isHttpServletRequest(ServletRequestEvent sre) {
        return RELEVANT_SERVLET_REQUEST_PROTOCOLS.contains(sre.getServletRequest().getScheme().toLowerCase());
    }

}
```

Finally the helper class that was isolated out to be able to deploy on weblogic and that is doing the vodoo of trying to repair the thread is the following.

```
package wahteverpackage;

import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.jboss.weld.contexts.AbstractBoundContext;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import LALALLALALALLA.commons.util.cdi.CdiUtil;

/**
 * This listener relates to the issue
 *
 * LALALLAMaint-3541 - Wildfly - WELD-001304 - More than one context active for scope type
 * javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped</a>
 *
 * We want to create a listener to tries to avoid the problem that once in wildlfy the HttpSessionDestructionContext is
 * activated during a session timeout, if the session timeout event blows up, the thread that processed the session
 * timeout will have its thread local state variables corrupted always activating this context implementation.
 */
public class LALALLAWildflyWELD001304ServletRequestListenerHelper {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(LALALLAWildflyWELD001304ServletRequestListenerHelper.class);

    /**
     * Try to access the {@link SessionScoped} context to see if our thread will be damaged by a
     *
     * {@code org.jboss.weld.exceptions.IllegalStateException: WELD-001304: More than one context active for scope type javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped}
     *
     * @return TRUE if the session scope for this specific thread has been corrupted. The corruption is most likely
     *         derived to a session timeout explosion with the
     *         {@link LALALLALALALLA.framework.web.security.LALALLASessionListener} blowing up when the sessionDestroyed
     *         is called.
     */
    public boolean isCurrentThreadCorruptedWithWELD001304Exception(BeanManager beanManager) {
        try {
            // usual
            beanManager.getContext(SessionScoped.class);
            return false;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            org.jboss.weld.exceptions.IllegalStateException duplicateActiveContextsExceptionExample = org.jboss.weld.logging.BeanManagerLogger.LOG
                    .duplicateActiveContexts(SessionScoped.class.getName());
            if (duplicateActiveContextsExceptionExample.getMessage().equals(e.getMessage())) {
                // We are hiting a thread that has been corrupted and the session context for this thread
                // as two implementation of the session scoped context currently active
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * The try to repair corrupted thread is concerned with the fact that the thread local memory of the current thread
     * is stating that the HttpSessionDestructionContext is active, and this memory state is not being cleared because
     * when the session timed out the process of handling the session timeout was interrupted due to some blow up
     * exception.
     *
     * To fix this of course the code that is blowing up should be repaired. But to be on the safe side we have this
     * work around code that will try to heal the thred and put it back to to a workable state.
     *
     */
    public void tryToRepairCorruptedThread(BeanManager beanManager) {
        LOGGER.error("The current thread appears to be corrupted facing the"
                + " WELD-001304: More than one context active for scope type javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped."
                + " See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58930939/wildflt-13-weld-001304-more-than-one-context-active-for-scope-type-javax-enterp "
                + " It is posisble that this thread has been used in the past to handle an http session timeout that blew up during the "
                + " io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.sessionDestroyed phase. "
                + " If this is the case it is very likely that the thread local memory of state of the current thread is corrupted"
                + "  with the wildfly HttpSessionDestructionContext stating that it is active when it should not be active at all."
                + " We will try to deactive this context.  ");
        AbstractBoundContext<HttpSession> httpSessionDestructionContext = getSessionDestructionContext(beanManager);
        if (httpSessionDestructionContext.isActive()) {
            LOGGER.warn(
                    "Our assumtion that the problem is that the wildfly HttpSessionDestructionContext is active is true. We will now try to cleanup the thread local of this thread by "
                            + " forcing this HttpSessionDestructionContext to deactivate  ");
            httpSessionDestructionContext.deactivate();
        } else {
            LOGGER.warn(
                    "The situation is not clear. two or more contexts are active for the session context, our expectation is that the two activate contexts are the org.jboss.weld.context.http.HttpSessionContext and the org.jboss.weld.module.web.context.http.HttpSessionDestructionContext "
                            + " but the HttpSessionDestructionContext seems not to be ACTIVE. ");
        }
    }

    /**
     * The HttpSessionDestructionContext obtained using the same technique as HttpContextLifecycle.
     *
     * @return The HttpSessionDestructionContext that we have seen to be active in requests where it should not be
     *         active.
     */
    // Ignore the fact that we are using fully qualified names
    // we want to be able to deploy this java class to weblogic
    // without getting explosions that imports at the class level are not prese
    @SuppressWarnings("squid:S1942")
    public AbstractBoundContext<HttpSession> getSessionDestructionContext(BeanManager beanManager) {
        // In a cdi container we get injected a a proxy to the bean manager
        // in org.jboss.weld.module.web.servlet.HttpContextLifecycle is getting the beanMangerImpl directly
        // and using a different technique to get the HttpSessionDestructionContext using the same approach as the
        return CdiUtil.getBeanByClass(beanManager,
                org.jboss.weld.module.web.context.http.HttpSessionDestructionContext.class);

    }

}
```

Finally, I will probably be opening an issue in :
https://issues.jboss.org/projects/WFLY/issues

Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks a lot for the explanation I learned a lot from your explanation.

In my case the thread gets corrupted due to RuntimeException thrown by HttpSessionListener. Let me explain how.

[SessionListenerBridge.java Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6Mmg.png)

- [SessionListenerBridge@WildFLy](https://github.com/undertow-io/undertow/blob/2.1.3.Final/servlet/src/main/java/io/undertow/servlet/core/SessionListenerBridge.java) executes doDestroy()
- doDestroy() calls my application's HttpSessionListener.sessionDestroyed()
- my application throws RuntimeException
- Remainder of session clearing logic is not executed as SessionListenerBridge do not handle the RuntimeException.(See the image for more detail)

I end up handling all Throwable in my Session-Listener to avoid loosing threads in production